# Nothing appears parsing a page

Tags: java, android, parsing, jsoup

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            // NB: controllate di importare le classi giuste
            // all'inizio ci deve essere org.jsoup

            // ricavo l'html della pagina con user agent desktop (Chrome) 
            // e timeout 30000
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.androidiani.com/forum")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22")
                    .timeout(30000).get();

            // prendo la tabella 
            // (con .first() ottengo il primo elemento, in questo caso l'unico )
            Element tabella = doc.getElementsByClass("floatcontainer").first();

            // prendo gli elementi che mi interessano dalla tabella
            Elements sezioni = tabella.getElementsByClass("forumtable td");
            for(Element sezione : sezioni)//per ogni sezione tra gli elementi ricavati prima
            {
                //ricavo ogni riga nella sezione
                Elements righe_sezione = sezione.getElementsByClass("foruminfo");                   
                for(Element riga : righe_sezione)
                {
                    //prelevo la cella delle info
                    Element info = riga.getElementsByClass("datacontainer").first();

                    // ricavo il titolo
                    // (con .text() ottengo il testo non formattato
                    String titolo = info.getElementsByClass("forumtitle").first().text();

                    // ricavo la descrizione
                    // (uso .first() per essere sicuro che sia proprio la descrizione
                    // e non i moderatori )
                    String descrizione = info.getElementsByTag("p").first().text();

                    // inserisco nei rispettivi arraylist
                    titoli.add(titolo);
                    descrizioni.add(descrizione);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // gestione dell'eccezione
            // ad esempio mostrare messaggio di errore o altro (qui nel logcat)
            Log.e("ESEMPIO", "ERRORE NEL PARSING");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I'm trying for the first time, to parse a html page to display a list of sections of a forum (androidiani.com/forum).but nothing appears and I can't understand why.the code  is on top.

Comment: is ur path correct? Check ur xpath...

Comment: The forum is in http://www.androidiani.com/forum so it's correct. Something else?

Comment: I can't find the error..i have Only a blank activity

Comment: what kind of debugging have you tried ?

Comment: I was starting from this tutorial http://www.anddev.it/index.php?topic=10886.0 and i use the developer tools of chrome to see the  html and css. is what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in these lines:

```
Element tabella = doc.getElementsByClass("floatcontainer").first();;
tabella.getElementsByClass("forumtable td")
```

It should be, as I understand the task:

```
Element tabella = doc.getElementById("forums");
Elements sezioni = tabella.select(".foruminfo.td");
```

Using Chrome's developer tools helps a lot for this type of job.

**UPDATE**

The working code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
try {
    // NB: controllate di importare le classi giuste
    // all'inizio ci deve essere org.jsoup

    // ricavo l'html della pagina con user agent desktop (Chrome)
    // e timeout 30000
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.androidiani.com/forum")
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22")
        .timeout(30000).get();

    // prendo la tabella
    // (con .first() ottengo il primo elemento, in questo caso l'unico )
    Element tabella = doc.getElementById("forums");

    // prendo gli elementi che mi interessano dalla tabella
    Elements sezioni = tabella.select(".foruminfo.td");
    for(Element sezione : sezioni)//per ogni sezione tra gli elementi ricavati prima
    {
        //ricavo ogni riga nella sezione
        Elements righe_sezione = sezione.getElementsByClass("foruminfo");
        for(Element riga : righe_sezione)
        {
            //prelevo la cella delle info
            Element info = riga.getElementsByClass("datacontainer").first();

            // ricavo il titolo
            // (con .text() ottengo il testo non formattato
            String titolo = info.getElementsByClass("forumtitle").first().text();

            // ricavo la descrizione
            // (uso .first() per essere sicuro che sia proprio la descrizione
            // e non i moderatori )
            String descrizione = info.getElementsByTag("p").first().text();

            // inserisco nei rispettivi arraylist

            System.out.println("titolo = " + titolo);
            System.out.println("descrizione = " + descrizione);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // gestione dell'eccezione
    // ad esempio mostrare messaggio di errore o altro (qui nel logcat)
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: and then? I can't udnderstan which elements i have to parse..i mean, ok `forums`, `.foruminfo.td` and??

Comment: i'm using chrome developer tools but i canìt understand what i have to write.

Comment: Try reading about CSS-selectors. `tabella.select` executes one. Basically, `tabella.select(".foruminfo.td")` is what you meant by `tabella.getElementsByClass("forumtable td")`. _Two_ classes are requested this way. And with `getElementsByClass(...)` you search by a _single_ class, so in your case it just didn't find anything.

Comment: i've tryied insert `.forumdata, .datacontainer and .forumtitle` after `forums and .foruminfo.td` but always blank activity :(

Comment: ehm...blank ahahah. This, is sooooo strange!!

Comment: Yeah, because I have console output.

Comment: I've tryied also with  `titoli.add(titolo);
                    descrizioni.add(descrizione);` that are the arrays but nothing. anything else?

Comment: aaaaa it works!!! it comes out after, i don't know how much time, but works ahaha

Comment: Better late than never, huh!